# How should I deal with Time Zones on a Client-Server app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, datetime, client-server

I have an iOS application and a rails backend.

The iOS client allows user to pick Dates in the (Year|Month|Day) format. No time is necessary, it's preferable if 00:00:00 is used.

What's the best practice for this, and what should I use?

1) Should the client convert times into UTC, and then save those to the server. And then when the client fetches times, convert it back into the user local time?

2) Should the client just push up whatever time it wants, and leave it for the server to decide what to do with it?

Comment: Don't think we can answer without knowing the client and server will do with those dates. Will they be shared among users? Available elsewhere? If you're only dealing with a date do you even want timezones?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm doing with my apps:

Backend/server only deals with UTC. Always store times in UTC into the MySQL database (or whatever database you're using).

Push the conversion of time differences logic to the client. Most clients have a third party solution dealing with conversion of time (for iOS, check: https://github.com/yannickl/YLMoment ).

In mobile clients, I would still store the times in UTC into the local database. The only time I do any conversion is when the date is being displayed on the UI. This allows for users to travel into different timezones and the dates will be updated to reflect the local timezone.